# Careers Candidate Search is Relentless

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When using the [Careers candidate search](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/candidate-search), the client-side code refuses to believe that changes to (at least) your Skills search criteria will be fruitless, and continuously double-checks with the server for results. While I appreciate its enthusiasm, the requests are excessive at around 6 per second:

[image: Network request log showing excessive requests]

You can test this by going to the search page and putting in either an unpopular tag, or one that doesn't exist, like "ja". I was able to reproduce this in Firefox 3.6, Chrome 11 and 13, IE 9 (for good measure), and Opera 11 (for Jeff's amusement).

A quick look at the code suggests that the problem might be in the `SearchResultsView.render` function, where `this.model.attributes.CurrentPage` is set to -1 when a zero-result response is returned. This causes `Search.LoadPage()` to be called later on, which I believe makes the search request again, and this request is handled by `SearchResultsView.render`. Provided this is correct, it seems that this leads to a loop so long as the response doesn't have any candidates to display.

Comment: Tim Stone, the most underpaid SE developer :)

Comment: @benjol that is completely unfair, we pay him handsomely with upvotes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Who knew a little unbounded recursion hidden in a callback was gonna get us a new testimonial?

[image: It's relentless I tell's ya!]

Should be bounded now :)  Thanks for the report.

Comment: @Tim, quick, add this to your resume!