# Tell me J.E, and tell me twice; What do you think of Careers.SO?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I was just looking at the Careers site to see if my up-to-date profile needed updating. (Who said "procrastination"?!?) And I noticed the "what people say about us" section on the front page.

> [image: Surely that's not Jon Ericson]

Apparently J.E. is a very influential user, because his feedback appears twice. Granted, it's pretty minor and I'm not sure if it classifies as a bug, but at least it's odd. If you want to make it look like people enjoy your site, you kinda want to go for "people" there. Plural.

So yeah, perhaps add a check to make sure you actually quote two different users. Otherwise, on rare occasions, it might look a bit odd.

Comment: people**S** with a giant S?

Comment: ^ get him Jeff!!

Comment: Twice? Are people not allowed to have the same name? Thats just a happy coincidence ;)

Comment: I'd love it if that was the actual cause @nicael. Same initials, same town.

Comment: @nicael Nope, not even the same initials, if they live in the same city.  They're fine if they're from different cities though.

Comment: Anyway, everything is clear; thats fake :D

Comment: What isn't fake here?

Comment: חיישינן לתרי יוסי בר שמעון? .....apparently not ;-)

Comment: ^^^^ [ *note to non-Talmudists: there is discussion if, when viewing any document, we need to be concerned about two people with the same name from the same town (see, e.g., [Gitin 24b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=24b&format=pdf))....the example name given is "יוסי," which means "Joseph," loosely -- hence the J.E.* ]

Comment: They should have just used [my testimonial](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91599/careers-candidate-search-is-relentless/91649#91649) anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although we're happy J.E. shares his appreciation of Careers, displaying two testimonials from the same user gives less information. We are now making sure not to display quotes from the same person twice.

Due to caching, this fix might take a few hours to become effective.

Thanks for your report!

Comment: J.E. and I thank you. As does J.E.